# Android Wear app connection timeout

Tags: timeout, httpurlconnection

I'm building an Android wear app that uses HTTPUrlConnection() to gather some data from a webpage. This works all perfectly fine in the Emulator, but does not on a real device (Moto 360 i use for testing). I ran the server on both the local network and external network, but somehow the real device ends up with a Connection timeout. It's not the server either, as i tried different computers, different software, and different networks with different routers. The Android manifest seems also fine. Am i doing something wrong, or could this be a bug?

```
try {
        // create the HttpURLConnection
        HttpURLConnection connection;

            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // just want to do an HTTP GET here
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        // uncomment this if you want to write output to this url
        //connection.setDoOutput(true);

        // give it 15 seconds to respond
        connection.setReadTimeout(15 * 1000);
        connection.connect();

        // read the output from the server
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }
        bodyHtml = stringBuilder.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //throw e;
    } finally {
        // close the reader; this can throw an exception too, so
        // wrap it in another try/catch block.
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="vendor.atestapp" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
<service android:name=".WearMessageListenerService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Log output:

```
09-09 00:50:50.177    3664-8913/vendor.atestapp W/System.err﹕ java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.39 (port 8080): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
09-09 00:50:50.177    3664-8913/vendor.atestapp W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:124)
09-09 00:50:50.177    3664-8913/vendor.atestapp W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
09-09 00:50:50.177    3664-8913/vendor.atestapp W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
09-09 00:50:50.177    3664-8913/vendor.atestapp W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
```

Comment: Probably a network or firewall problem. You could try whether your watch can access an external address like `http://www.google.com`. Or maybe your URL has errors, because `/192.168.1.39` seems strange.

Comment: A Wear-firewall problem? How do i solve something like that? With a disabled firewall on the server, i can perfectly connect from the Wear emulator, but not from the real Wear-device. My URL is according to System.output(): `"http://" + host + ":" + port + "/index.html"` resulting in `http://192.168.1.39:8080/index.html` I don't see any problem with that URL, which is also perfectly accessible in the browser. I tried removing `http://` but that only resulted in an Exception saying `Protocol not found: 192.168.1.39:8080/index.html`

Comment: Not firewall on your watch, but firewall on your PC running the server. Also possible that your server doesn't bind to 0.0.0.0, but only one of your network interfaces. Emulator can access this, but maybe watch not.

Comment: Found the problem, HTTPUrlConnection doesn't work on Wear. Google disabled it on all of their devices (yet you can perfectly add it in your code), but apparently forgot to disable it in the Emulator.

Comment: This is bad. I suppose you write your own answer. This could help some poor soles, because the comments might not be read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem! HTTPUrlConnection doesn't work on Wear. Google disabled it, yet you can perfectly code it. Apparently this is some sort of policy by Google, yet they forgot to disable it in their emulator.

Alternative (this is how i do it now): Use HTTPUrlConnection on your phone, and use the MessageApi to communicate with your Wear device.

Answer (score 1):

Android watch will not connect to the internet via the bluetooth connection to the phone, UrlHTTPConnection is disabled because it is not a Wear issue, as I will **BUT** it will connect when connected via WiFi.

Unfortunately, most devices pre mid-2015 don't support WiFi :-( More unfortunate, is that Android Wear App for handhelds won't bridge Bluetooth from the watch with the internet from the world.

UrlHTTPConnection is enabled because it is not a Wear issue. The guilty is the Wear-App on the handheld.

Obviously, it is not viable *"for life"* but for curiosity, if you connect your device via WiFi and disable Bluetooth on your phone *(it always prefers BT for power considerations)* it will miraculously begin to work.